# Laravel API with Bearer token - Middleware auth:api

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to create an API with Bearer Token but I can't figure it out:

1. What does the `route::middleware('auth:api')` do
2. Where's the code of `route::middleware('auth:api')`

So, I have the following code in my `Routes\Api.php` file:

```
Route::get('/login', function (Request $request) 
{
    if(Auth::guard()->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password]) == FALSE)
        return response()->json(['status' => FALSE]);

    $user = Users::select('id', 'name', 'api_token', 'created_at')->where('email', $request->email)->firstOrFail();

    return response()->json(['status' => TRUE, 'user' => $user]);
});

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/bookings', function (Request $request)
{
    return response()->json(['its working!']);
});
```

I'm able to successfully connect to the route `/login` and retrieve the `api_token`. Now this token must be used in the `/bookings` route in order to authenticate.

I was hopping the `middleware('auth:api')`verify my CURL headers for the `Authorization: Bearer zzzzzzzzz`, but its not working.

So basically I need to understand how do I change the code logic behind `auth:api` or if I should create a new middleware and check for the request headers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Diclamer

If you need custom code to handle authentication you should create your own middleware and authentication guard and use it instead of the default one that Laravel provides.

#### Your questions

> What does the `route::middleware('auth:api')` do

It states that the route should implement the middleware "auth" and the middleware group "api".

> Where's the code of `route::middleware('auth:api')`

All middleware in Laravel is defined in `app/Http/Kernel.php`.

In there you will probably see something like

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    ....,
    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];
```

and

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...,
    'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
];
```

This means that a route using the middleware `auth:api` implements the api middleware group (in this case the `ThrottleRequests` and `SubstituteBinding` middleware) and the auth middleware (`Authenticate`).

The actual authentication guard used depends on the configuration in your `auth.php` config file:

```
'guards' => [
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

In the case above a TokenGuard is used (`laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/TokenGuard.php`).

So to answer your question, the code for the auth middleware can be found at

```
laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php
```

Comment: Besides from your answer, I should state that the `api_token` should be sent as a URL parameter and not as a header. Everything is now working fine.